# CSS Stop Working Before Install SSL Certificate Install

Tags: php, html, css, ssl, web

i have this site https://carefinders.kgllsolutions.com.
All the inputs and css styles will not work anymore, because i installed a SSL Certificate.

In local server i run it great but with ssl not showing the correct input size and correct fonts.
I will appreciate some advices. I have read that changing all href to https but all my css are stored on same server.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try is to use the developer tools in your web browser and look at the network tab, there you can check to see if your files are loading correctly.